# The Purcell effect, it's influence on the lifetime and quantum yield (of fluorophores)

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics

So I've been looking into the Purcell effect and how it interacts with fluorophores (fluorescent molecules). The Purcell arises when you have a dipole in a cavity or even just near a dielectric or metal interface. It can then enhance the emission of the dipole in comparison to free space.

Now for fluorophores two factors are affected by the Purcell effect, the quantum yield and the decay time (aka, relaxation time or lifetime). Now what I don't know is when and by how much either is affected. This is important for me to know because fluorophores are intrinsically limited as they can only emit 1 photon and absorb one at the same time. Being a bit more specific, they have a saturation in the sense that they can not absorb a new photon if they're still in the exited state. Now I know that for high quantum yield fluorophores the Purcell effect should mostly affect the decay time. 
Now what I would like to know is there a good way to find how much both quantum yield and decay time are affected (approximation). What happens to a saturation curve of fluorophores, what changes, slope, offset, something else?

Also any sources of information  (fundamental) are also very much appreciated, especially the fundamentals of the Purcell effect. Like I can understand why there's an enhancement of the power emitted if the dipole is in a resonant cavity, as that intuitively makes sense, however I have more trouble understanding this if a dipole is just very close to a dielectric interface.

Ps I have a good understanding of optics/photonics but as good as none about quantum.

Comment: Are you asking for a quantitative formula? In this case, relating what to what? Because you have already given yourself a heuristic explanation.

Comment: Yes I'm looking for a quantitative formula and possibly some more background reading, especially to get a better understanding of what is fundamentally happening.
As I know what the effect is but not why it happens or how exactly.

Comment: As to what kind of relation. Purcell factor, related to the (avg) lifetime and quantum yield for a fluorophore subjected to that Purcell factor.

Comment: The only reference I know about it regards the Purcell effect in superconducting qubits. I'm not sure if that is of interest to you.

Comment: I don't think that will help. A fluorophore, can be basically  considered a dipole emitter when it's emitting a photon. However when absorbing and when relaxing it's of course a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

The Purcell effect can be summarized by the following infographics, originally published here: [Link](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/pavel-kolesnichenko-8a853547_outreach-physics-photonics-activity-7153146093478797312-0GWb?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop). Although, one fluorophore can absorb and emit one photon, it is still a probabilistic process that depends on transition probabilities (that is probability of the fluorophore to absorb light) and density of fluorophore-related and photonic states (defining the number of emitted photons per time from an ensemble of fluorophores). These factors contribute to the statement of the known Fermi's Golden Rule. Thus, when ensemble is considered, then not all fluorophores will absorb photons, and emission will also be governed by this probabilistic Rule.

[image: Purcell effect explained]

The fluorescence quantum yield $\Phi_f$ can be defined through radiative $k_r$ and (cumulative) non-radiative $k_{nr}$ rates as
$$
\Phi_f=\frac{k_r}{k_r+k_{nr}}.
$$

As seen from the infographics, the Purcell effect affects rates of decay processes. It is now known that it can affect not only radiative $k_r$ but also non-radiative $k_{nr}$ rates, provided the latter are of a dipole-dipole or scattering interaction type (see, for example, [HERE](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpcc.3c07508)).

In answering the posed question, the tricky part comes from the following two facts.

The first one is that the Purcell effect has some dispersion, i.e., Purcell enhancement is wavelength-dependent (i.e., for different wavelengths there are different Purcell enhancement factors). The precise wavelength-dependence is ultimately defined by the nature and geometry of materials used to shape the photonic environment, and can be found from simulations (e.g., using transfer-matrix method).

The second fact is regarding the ability to answer the question: what is the nature of non-radiative pathways that contribute to $k_{nr}$ and what is their energetics. For that, you would need to know quantum-mechanical specifics of the considered fluorophores.

Provided the dispersion of the Purcell enhancement as well as the wavelengths (energies) of radiative $\lambda_r$ and non-radiative $\lambda_{nr}$ processes are known, and introducing Purcell factors at these wavelengths, $p_r$ and $p_{nr}$, respectively, the quantum yield $\tilde{\Phi}_f$, modified by the Purcell effect, can be written as (only one non-radiative porcess is assumed here)

$$
\tilde{\Phi}_f=\frac{p_rk_r}{p_rk_r+p_{nr}k_{nr}}.
$$
It is clear from this expression that quantum yield can only be modified if Purcell effect has at least non-flat dispersion, and more precisely when $p_r\neq p_{nr}$.