# How to interpret the value of the Purcell factor?

Tags: optics, photons, quantum-information, quantum-electrodynamics, photon-emission

I am a little bit confused regading the Purcell effect.

If someone tells me that the Purcell factor of a system is 4? then does it means that the spontaneous emission is enhanced by 4 times the original value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the spontaneous emission rate in this case is enhanced by 4.

More on the Purcell effect here: [LINK](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/410790/the-purcell-effect-its-influence-on-the-lifetime-and-quantum-yield-of-fluorop)